# htacces rewrite url not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes
# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)$ product_details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

my page product_details.php is a individual page that the products listed in index.php refer to through a link like:

```
<a href="product_details.php?id=<?php echo $prod['product_id'];  ?>&name=<?php echo friendlyURL($prod['name']);  ?>"
```

Which results this:
    http://www.imprimanteetichete.ro/product_details.php?id=1&name=imprimanta-de-etichete-zebra-105sl-plus-203dpi

I have tried many times with different techniques on the Rewrite rule, it just doesn't work. I'm new to .htaccess, but it seems like a basic thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `^products/([0-9]+)/(.*)$` or `^products/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)$` which might be safer

Comment: Nothing different, still shows the complete url

Comment: Still shows complete URL? Do you want to rewrite URL or Redirect?

Comment: yes, still complete url. I want to have seo friendly URLs, meaning to show `products/imprimanta-de-etichete-zebra-gc420d-1`

Comment: It doesn't work even with: `RewriteRule ^products/([0-9])$ product_details.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: `products/1/imprimanta-de-etichete-zebra-gc420d-1` would match your rule

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

or

```
RewriteBase http://example.com/
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)$ product_details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: RewriteBase / , does nothing different
`RewriteBase http://www.imprimanteetichete.ro/` gets me a internal server error

Answer (score 0):

You can have these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product_details\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /products/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /product_details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```